# Unable to map assembly when running multiple test projects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, resharper

When running only a single test project, all mappings work fine and all of my tests pass.

However, when I run my unit test project at the same time as my integration test project, all of my tests fail with the following error.

```
----> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument)
----> NHibernate.MappingException : persistent class
```

The assembly NHibernate seems unable to find is the assembly running the test.

My mappings looks like the following.

```
MsSqlConfiguration msSqlConfiguration =
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConnectionString);
var cfg = new TestConfiguration();

return Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(msSqlConfiguration)
   .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
      .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<ClassInFolderToMap>(cfg)))
      .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I have also tried replacing the AutoMap with an explicit Mapper file, however, this resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was related to my test runner. Or at least my test runner was able to fix the issue.

The issue was fixed by checking "Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests" in my Resharper settings.

[image]